# whether or not in adverbial clauses

Tags: conjunctions

I'm wondering whether "or not" can be omitted in an adverbial clause headed by "whether".
Which of the following is correct?

1. Whether he knows Peter personally or not, he will visit him today.
2. Whether he knows Peter personally, he will visit him today.
3. No matter whether he knows Peter personally or not, he will visit him today.
4. No matter whether he knows Peter personally, he will visit him today.
5. No matter if he knows Peter personally or not, he will visit him today.
6. No matter if he knows Peter personally, he will visit him today.

Inputs from native speakers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: #2 is completely non-idiomatic, because we normally expect that when ***whether*** is used in such contexts, there will be an associated ***or not***. Personally, I don't like any of your ***no matter*** variants much. I'd use ***regardless of whether***, which seems fine to me regardless of whether you explicitly mention the alternative [or not!]. To my ear, #6 is actually a slightly less idiomatic version of *[It is] no matter **that** he knows Peter* (i.e. - implying that he *does* know him, but this doesn't matter / isn't important in the context of the visit).

Comment: I'd say you can't drop *or not* in that use. It's not required in sentences like *I'm not sure whether [or not] she'll be there*, which means that *Regardless of whether he knows Peter personally, he will visit him today* is OK, even though it means the sane as *Whether or not he knows Peter personally, he wil visit hin today*.

Answer (score 1):

A native speaker would not say *any* of those. Not necessarily because of grammatical structure, but because we do not use the phrases "*no matter if*" or "*whether or not*" in the kind of context you are describing.

A 'wether clause' introduces a binary choice, usually to say that something will happen regardless of either option. For example:

> Whether it is raining or not, I'm going running tomorrow.

This shows that the outcome does not depend on the weather - you, the person going running, have made the choice that either situation will not prevent you from doing so.

The reason your examples are so strange is that while the first person speaking may not know whether 'he' knows Peter or not, it's a fair assumption that 'he' and Peter are aware of whether they are acquainted. So, the decision for 'him' to visit Peter *may* actually depend on one or the other! Maybe the reason he is visiting is because he *does* know him?

What I think you may be trying to say, and is certainly something a native speaker might say, is:

> Whether he knows Peter personally or not, I don't know. But he is visiting him today.

The difference here is that you are not attaching the whether-clause to the visit as a dependency. You are simply saying that you are unaware which option is true, and regardless of your knowledge on the matter, there is a visit taking place.

Answer (score 0):

In some situations,

***Whether he knows Peter personally or not, he will visit him today.***

might be considered correct. However, I would prefer to say

#### ***Whether or not he knows Peter personally, he will visit him today.***

The second one is incorrect. As for the third one, ***No matter whether or not he knows Peter personally, he will visit him today*** sounds better to me. But you may omit ***or not*** if you wish and it will still be correct.

#### ***No matter whether he knows Peter personally, he will visit him today***

I personally would not use "No matter if..."

I hope this helps.